# Numpy cannot save with certain name(s)

Tags: numpy, save, filenames

I found out that numpy cannot save with a certain name.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = range(100)
>>> np.save('con', a)
�NUMPY F {'descr': '<i4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (100,), }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\gilgarad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 509, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gilgarad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 587, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

Why am I getting this error? I am sure that this is not because of the length of file name because I have saved some other files with the other three character length name and was successful.

Is there some kind of rules about the file names that I should know if when I save some numpy file?

Comment: The file name is not the problem.  It's actually going to save it at `con.npy`.  It works for me.  I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I tried with a several linux computers, and it works as you said. however it has the same problem with my colleagues' computers that are using  windows 10.

Comment: Searching on `windows reserved filenames` produced http://kizu514.com/blog/forbidden-file-names-on-windows-10/, which lists `CON` as a reserved name in Windows.  This special meaning goes way back - short for console.

Comment: Ohhh that's so perfect answer I wanted. You should write it as an answer. I was not too fast to realize the hole in my question, but you did find. Thanks a lot. My one last question is that, it seems like the name is reserved whatever the extension is, did I understand correctly?